# word2vec: weighted How can I give negative training data?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

Im reusing word2vec for products on my website and users. I would like to say that a user is NEGATIVELY associated to a product if he has visited the page < 5 seconds and POSITIVELY if he spent > 30 seconds on the page. Is there a way to specify this in word2vec? Or is there some other tool that enables this?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not well defined but I think you want to store the relation of user with the product which has nothing to do with word2vec. word2vec essentially gives you a mapping from strings to contiguous domain vectors. In your problem you should give a separate new feature of User-Product relationship (NEGATIVE or POSITIVE) along with the word2vec features and you can let the model retrain the word-embeddings according to this new POSITIVE/NEGATIVE feature while solving your particular task. This way the model will adjust the word-embeddings and get some of the desired effect of the POSITIVE/NEGATIVE features.

Please be more elaborate so that I can answer your question in a better way.